# Cannot add a nested relation or an element column to a table containing a SimpleContent column. in C#

Tags: c#

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
System.IO.StringReader xmlSR = new System.IO.StringReader(xml);
ds.ReadXml(xmlSR);

DataTable dtIItems = new DataTable();
DataTable dtHotelInformation = new DataTable();
dtIItems = ds.Tables[30];
dtHotelInformation = ds.Tables[51];
DataColumn DCHotelImage = dtHotelInformation.Columns[2];
var Items = dtIItems;
Items.Columns.Add(DCHotelImage.ColumnName,DRHotelImage.DataType);
```

When I add column from other DataTable this run time error message returns

> Cannot add a nested relation or an element column to a table
>   containing a SimpleContent column.

**Note**: I can`t make any change on xml files cause its provided from third party

Comment: check whether your xml have the any same element name with a  some different structure somewhere in the document. eg: <name>john</name>  and some where <Name role="admin"><first>adam</first></Name>